# Is there a way to split row values into separate columns with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a pandas data frame that reads like this:

```
0   (dev_id='A', accon_time='B', start_time='C',end_time='D')
1   (dev_id='E', accon_time='F', start_time='G',end_time='H')
2   (dev_id='I', accon_time='J', start_time='K',end_time='L')
```

The current shape of this data frame is (574,1) when I actually want it to be (574,4) where each of the 4 comma separated values in each row are actually split between 4 separate columns.

Is there any way to do this?

- This data is coming from a SQL Alchemy query

I've tried converting my query into a pandas series first and then using Series.str.split however the results are the same as the original data frame.

```
ser = pd.Series(qry)
ser.str.rsplit(pat=",", n=4, expand=True)
print(ser)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=ser)
print(df)
```

This is what i'm using to query my data:

```
class Trip(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'trip'
    dev_id = Column(String(50), primary_key=True)
    accon_time = Column(Integer)
    start_time = Column(Integer)
    end_time = Column(Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "(dev_id='%s', accon_time='%s', start_time='%s',end_time='%s')" 
          % (self.dev_id, self.accon_time, self.start_time, self.end_time)

qry = session.query(Trip).\
        filter(Trip.accon_time.between(20190620000000, 20190621000000)).\
        filter(Trip.start_time <= 20190620145813).\
        filter(Trip.end_time <= 20190620151400).\
        filter(Trip.end_time >= 20190620145600)
```

This returns a list like this:

> (dev_id='A', accon_time='B', start_time='C',end_time='D'),(dev_id='E',
>   accon_time='F', start_time='G',end_time='H'),(dev_id='I',
>   accon_time='J', start_time='K',end_time='L')

Converting my query results into a pandas data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=qry)
print(df)
```

Comment: hey just to be sure is your elements in df a string? i.e. "(dev_id='A', accon_time='B', start_time='C',end_time='D')"?

Comment: you should try 
`ser = ser.str.rsplit(pat=",", n=4, expand=True)`
instead of `ser.str.rsplit(pat=",", n=4, expand=True)` in your example

Comment: Honestly you should probably pull your data out as data instead of putting it through `__repr__` and then trying to unpack your string afterwards.

Comment: @kkawabat just tried it out, it returns an empty series like this:                                          
           0
 0   NaN
1   NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parsing example `ser.str.rsplit(pat=",", n=4, expand=True)` returns the output of ser, you need to catch the output or it wont do anything

Try this for the parsing:

```
qry =   ["(dev_id='A', accon_time='B', start_time='C',end_time='D')",
"(dev_id='E', accon_time='F', start_time='G',end_time='H')",
"(dev_id='I', accon_time='J', start_time='K',end_time='L')"]
ser = pd.Series(qry)
df = ser.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([val.split('=')[1] for val in x[1:-1].split(',')]))
df.columns = ['dev_id', 'accon_time', 'start_time', 'end_time']
```

for each row of ser `.appy()` I take the string and remove the paranteses `x[1:-1]` then split on the commas `.split(',')` this will give me a list of key value literals (i.e. `["dev_id='A'", " accon_time='B'", " start_time='C'", "end_time='D'"]`). Then for each literal I split it on '=' and return the second element which is the actual value `.split('=')[1]`.

if you don't want the "`'`" in your elements strip it at the end with `.strip('\'')`

```
   ser = ser.apply(lambda x:[val.split('=')[1].strip('\'') for val in x[1:-1].split(',')])
```

output:

```
  dev_id accon_time start_time end_time
0    'A'        'B'        'C'      'D'
1    'E'        'F'        'G'      'H'
2    'I'        'J'        'K'      'L'
```

Comment: Just tried this out, it's raising a type error.                                                        
"TypeError: 'Trip' object is not subscriptable".

Comment: I think that has to do with your Trip class. I assume that qry is a list of str outputs. try qry = [repr(x) for x in qry]?